# Using list of strings to access data frame variables in R

Tags: r, string, list, variables, dataframe

I have a series of data frames with the same columns:

```
d1 <- data.frame('a' = c(1,2), 'b' = c('x','y'))
d2 <- data.frame('a' = c(3,4), 'b' = c('z','m'))
d3 <- data.frame('a' = c(5,6), 'b' = c('n','o'))
```

I want to bind them together. One way is by doing this:

```
do.call("rbind", list(d1, d2, d3)) # this works
```

However, this inefficient when you have many data frames. I can create a string that generates the data frame names:

```
df.name <- rep(paste0('d',c(1:3))) # creates a list 'd1','d2','d3'
do.call("rbind", list(df.name)) # rbinds 'd1','d2','d3' as strings
```

However, when you do this it binds 'd1','d2','d3' as strings. What would I need to do so R will treat the list values as variables representing data frames?

Comment: See `?mget` and `?ls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` with `paste`

```
 library(data.table)
 rbindlist(mget(paste0("d", 1:3)))
```

If there are many objects and have the same pattern i.e. "d" followed by some numbers, use `ls`

```
rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern="d\\d+")))
```